# Changing wordpress default language

Tags: php, multi-language, language

I'm trying to change the wordpress default language from english to swedish. I uploaded the language directory to wp-content with the swedish .mo file.

I've defined language in the config.php file but it won't update, when I'm logged in and under updates I can see an option that says restore core files with swedish, so I know its working, but when I update it is still is english.

Also under settings --> general there is no language option.

I have tried wp native dashboard but it crashed my website.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify what you tring to achive? Localiz theme ? Localize Admin UI ? What means "wp native dashboard" - you using some plugins to customize UI? How have you specify language in `wp-config.php`? How the spedish mo file calls? more info please.

Comment: I installed wordpress in english and now I want the back and front end interface to be swedish, I downloaded the swedish language, sv_SE.mo an uploaded it to wp-content/languges. Then I defined the language in the wp-config.php file and replaced it on the server. But it is still english

Comment: Language in config defined as `define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If/When you want to have wordpress in your own language you could/should download the swedish version imho.

Go and look  [here](http://sv.wordpress.org/) for the translated package. Because thats the best way to do.
Only having some language files doesn't do always the trick.
Download the package from the link I mentioned, unzip/untar unrar or whatever you do/want and just overwrite it through ftp.

Don't worry it wont overwrite any of your settings made in wp-config.php (because it has not even a wp-config.php!). Settings you may have made in core-files will be lost but that would always happen at updates if done. Neither will it "kill" your childtheme(s) or whatever. And if you already have  `define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');` in wp-config.php then your good to go.

About wp native dashboard (the plugin) is only for you as user/admin to see and not for your visiters (Till they login and make the setting in backend themselves). Btw I love that plugin because my native is different from my wordpress language we use and works flawless.(We use Version 1.3.12 & WP3.71 without any problems)
 
When it brakes your wordpress you could/should check if wordpress has other problems (just as reminder if a plugin not works or maybe (worse case) brakes your wordpress, it is not always that plugin but can also be a combination with other plugins)

To activate debug go to wp-config.php and change setting to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`
A little helpfull code we use is following (Only have to set true or false in the first code line)

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // Or false
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // writes errors down in wp-content/debug.log
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
}
```

You could create the logfile (debug.log) yourself by hand in folder wp-config, be aware that it shows a lot and don't forget to disable it after all is working again.
(We work offline, in a sandbox, and always test with debug activated to be sure that it has online no issues).